# what is the regex syntax to recognize 1 or possibly 2 or possibly 3 numeric characters in a row separated by underscores?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am facing the same problem. **pattern = '.*RESPONDENT_[0-9].*.csv.gz';**
using above command I am getting 4 results but removing .* from the begning of pattern, I am getting 0 results. please help

RESPONDENT_0_0_0.csv.gz

RESPONDENT_1_0_0.csv.gz

PROJECT_SLICE_RESPONDENT_0_0_0.csv.gz

PROJECT_SLICE_RESPONDENT_1_0_0.csv.gz

Answer (score 0):

This will work for the regexp

```
RESPONDENT(_\d){1,3}\.csv\.gz
```

Just remember to escape the backslashes in the Snowflake literal. It will (probably) need to be:

```
'RESPONDENT(_\\d){1,3}\\.csv\\.gz'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out(supports +3 digits), i gave it a few tests [here](https://regex101.com/):

```
^.*_\d.*$
```